# Java handle errors & exceptions

Tags: java, android

I have a class that allows to download a file from the internet:

```
public String download(String URL) {

try {
 if(somethingbad) {
  // set an error?
  return false; 
 }
}
//...
catch (SocketException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(InterruptedIOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Now, I am calling this function in another class and i want to show a message that will help me figure out why this will not work.

what can i do to display something like this?

```
HTTPReq r = new HTTPReq("http://www.stack.com/api.json");    
if(r.err) {
 showMessage(getMessage());
}
```

and the `getMessage()` will return the `SocketException`  or `IOException`  or even "empty url" if the URL is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I do not think you need all these:

SocketException, UnsupportedEncodingException, ClientProtocolException since they extend IOException

but if you want you can do this:

```
public String download(String URL) throws IOException, Exception {

    try {
        if(somethingbad) {
            throws new Exception("My Message);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

And then in your other file:

```
try {
    // some stuff
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // do something with e.getMessage();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // do something with e.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: catch(IOException) should go before catch(Exception). Otherwise IOExceptions will go into the first catch block.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just doing e.printStackTrace() inside the catch blocks, throw the exception back like so:

```
throw e;
```

Then you can surround the calling code like so:

```
try {
    HTTPReq r = new HTTPReq("http://www.stack.com/api.json");
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Show error message
}
```

Comment: and i would just do : e.getMessage() from my other class?? Also, how would i trigger a getMessage() if the `if(somethingbad) {` fails?

Comment: You have to modify  the signature of download method to indicate that it throws exceptions using the throws clause. An IDE should help you with the proper syntax.

Comment: I am using android studio and still don't get it

Comment: > and i would just do : e.getMessage() from my other class?? 

You could if you wanted to get the message inside the catch block.

> Also, how would i trigger a getMessage() if the if(somethingbad) { fails?


What sets the value of somethingbad? If download method throws an exception, the control will go into the appropriate catch block. The method will not continue to execute.